# WP Toolkit DatePicker won't update value

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-8, datepicker

So in developing an app for Windows Phone 8, I've run into the following problem with the toolkit.

Edit: The following is the complete code for a page which reproduces the problem:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
     xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="MyDate" />
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

This looks right, and lets the user select a date, but never updates its value.  After clicking on it you are presented with the date selection page.  No matter what you do on this page, when you return the DatePicker is set back to today's date.

I successfully use the DatePicker on another page.  This is on a specific page that I am having this problem.

My real question is, how do I debug the behavior of this element?  How can I determine what is causing the element not to update when you select another date?

Edit 2:
Obviously there is something else going on here with my app.  Hence my need to debug a running element, or at least find out why it isn't doing what I expect it to.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code for this specific page?

Comment: You can, but I didn't want to burden you. I know how annoying "This is my code, please make it work" questions are... that's why I just asked how to debug it. When I get home tonight I'll try reducing the page code to the smallest example which reproduces the bug, and I'll post that.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem I was running into was that I had initialization code in the OnNavigatedTo event for my page.

Every time you select a date using the DatePicker, you are actually navigating to a new page.  When the date selection is confirmed, you then navigate back to your original page.  Since my initialization code was in the OnNavigatedTo event, that meant every time a date was selected the page re-initialized itself.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the scenario, I usually check the e.NavigationMode arguments in the OnNavigaterTo event, and return when I'm getting back from a listpicker/datepicker:

```
  if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
                return;
```